# ESB 4.5.1 Windows service

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 has installation package to instal ESB 4.0.3 as Windows service.  On WSO2 ESB 4.5.1, there is no such package to install ESB 4.5.1 as Windows service.

1. Are there any reason that the package to install WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 as Windows service is removed?
2. Where we can find the package to install WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 as Windows service?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That feature has been removed from WSO2 products after Carbon 4.0.0 (which WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 is based on) This [post](http://engwar.com/post/678) may be helpful for you if you need to configure it using 3rd party projects.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same issue with WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 and tried the fee YAJSW (Dileepas answer) answered. But did not work.

Then I referred to this post [Running .bat as Windows Service](https://serverfault.com/questions/54676/how-to-create-a-service-running-a-bat-file-on-windows-2008-server) and was able to run WSO2 ESB as a service with these products:

- [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/): Great application for service management. But costly
- [AppToService](http://www.basta.com/Product.aspx?pid=22#.ULnpopPjlbs): Simple and easy. That's the product I choosed. (there is free 2.2 version available)

I'm now using AppToService - just adds the WSO2 ESB .bat as service.

Unfortunately except the free AppToService, all other products I tried did not work properly (as a real windows service). The java wrappers (like YAJSW) are somehow too complicated, as it is replacing the existing .bat scripts - and I don't want that either.

Answer (score 1):

When you use YAJSW to run any WSO2 Carbon 4.0 and higher versioned products you need to use the minimal wrapper.conf configured to run WSO2 Carbon products. 
To get the wrapper.conf and required steps please refer the Carbon documentation on "Installing as a Windows Service" at [1]

Thanks,
Dileepa

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Carbon403/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service

Answer (score 0):

You can run any Carbon 4.0.0 upward products as a Windows Service using [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://nssm.cc/usage. 
Just inform **wso2server.bat** file location and be happy :)